# referencing files in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, reference

If I reference a file in a silverlight project, is that file going to be looked at on the local pc or on the server (using silverlight 4 running in the browser)?

For instance if I opened up a StreamReader and gave it "C:\test.txt" (assuming silverlight had permission to read that directory, which I assume in this trivial example it wouldn't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you had permissions for that file* - which you don't, it would be on the local (client) side. A SL4 app running on the browser does not have permissions to acecss arbitrary files on the client computer. It does have access to a special location, the *IsolatedStorage*, which is located somewhere buried in the user directory, but you can't use a StreamReader directly to open a file from there, you need to use the IsolatedStorage classes to do it.

If you want to access a file on the server side, you need to explicitly expose it, for example using a web / WCF service.

Comment: cheers, new to the SL stuff and just been asked to look at something and this wasn't clear elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure answer is `local PC` however question is not 100% clear.

Silverlight has no access to server file structure, except via web links .
Its running on client machine and communicates to server by webserver calls usually.